# Pyramid code problem : object not defined

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this code block, it produces

> Runtime error 1004 : application-defined or object defined error

But VBA is working and the debug line should be

```
py.Range(py.Cells(row, column + level), py.Cells(row, column - level)).Value = "*"
```

How to fix it?

```
Dim wantnum As Integer
Dim py As Worksheet
Dim inputs As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim level As Integer    

Set py = Sheets("sheet4")

inputs = InputBox(" Enter the pyrimad level you want")

row = 1
column = inputs
level = 0

For count = 0 To inputs

    py.Range(py.Cells(row, column + level), py.Cells(row, column - level)).Value = "*"
    row = row + 1
    level = level + 1
    
    Debug.Print Error$(count)

Next count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Pyramid()
    Dim wantnum As Integer
    Dim py As Worksheet
    Dim inputs As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim level As Integer

    Set py = Sheets("sheet4")

    inputs = InputBox(" Enter the pyrimad level you want")

    row = 1
    column = inputs
    level = 0

    For count = 1 To inputs
        
        py.Range(py.Cells(row, column + level), py.Cells(row, column - level)).Value = "*"
        
        row = row + 1
        level = level + 1

        'Debug.Print Error$(count)

    Next count

End Sub
```